How can I check if the value of Azure DevOps Variable provided by Variable Group (Key Vault) is empty?
I'd like to check in an Azure DevOps Pipeline if an paramter of my template is empty.
This works fine as long as I use normal variables or explict set the parameters in the yml file.
Is there any way to check if the value is empty?
The following doesn't work for Variables provided by a variable group that is linked to an azure key vault.
  - task: DummyTask@1
    displayName: 'Magic'
    condition: eq('$(MyPassword)', '')```


Update your YAML like as below:
- task: DummyTask@1
  displayName: 'Magic'
  condition: eq(variables['MyPassword'], '')

This can work as expected in my pipelines.
